# how to use the parameters in main method in C

Tags: c

I am trying to run a main method in C but am having trouble. here is what I have

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc == 0)
        return 0;
    printf("%s \n", argv[0]);
    main(--argc,++argv);
}
```

in command I write this, ./main roses are red!

But it does not run, I am sure it will print this on the screen

r

o

s

e

s

a

r

e

r

e

d

!

Am I correct?

Comment: Does it even compile? I'm positive there's a restriction on calling `main`

Comment: You should avoid calling main recursively.

Comment: I am curious to see what would happen

Comment: Calling main recursively is not forbidden in C. (It is in C++, IIRC)

Comment: What you want to achieve through this code. Just printing the arguments. There is the better way, try on google, "command line argument in c".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output that you are seeing does **not** seem correct to me.

So, let's attempt to run your code.

```
[12:21pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] ./foo 
./foo 
[12:21pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] ./foo roses are red
./foo 
roses 
are 
red 
[12:21pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] ./foo "roses are red"
./foo 
roses are red
```

Comment: Why does it print out words not letters, are the int pointers pointing to the beginning of each word? I thought it was for every letter

Comment: @JamesCarter: For the second example, `./foo roses are red`, the 2 variables `argc` and `argv` will look like: `argc = 4` and `argv = {"./foo", "roses", "are", "red", nullptr}`. So `argv[1]` points to a string `"roses"`.

Answer (score 1):

argv[0] will hold the program name, argv[1] will hold roses and so on. To print thoses strings, I suggest you to use something like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;
  for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    printf("%s \n", argv[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Note: your function returns no value. Main should return int unconditionally:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(!argc)
        return 0;
    printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
    return main(--argc,++argv);
 /* ^^^^^^ */
}
```

BTW: (if it is called as `./main roses are red!`) it would print:

```
./main
roses
are
red!
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  In C, it is specifically OK for the `main()` function to lack a `return` statement.  This will cause it to return 0 implicitly.  See n1256 section 5.1.2.2.3, "Program termination": "reaching the `}` that terminates the `main` function returns a value of 0."

Comment: What you say is correct for c99. But making the function return type dependent on the program flow doen not look nice. IMHO the compiler should issue a warning. (and basically: I don't care if it is in the standard, it is just *standardised sloppiness* )

Comment: The real issue is that this is really just a comment on style, which is subjective, and not an answer.  This question calls for an objective answer.

Comment: There is an extra complication: main() is called in two ways: once by the crt, and once by main, recursively. Should *both* calls result in a zero return, just because the function name happens to be "main" ? What about tail-recursion? And I'd like to comment on the style of the Standard, too. It is terrible! ;-)

Comment: The question about "should" is a question you might want to ask the committee... the fact here is that both calls *do* result in a zero return, as specified by the standard.  If you have comments about the standard, this is not the place to do it.

Comment: Tail recursion is an optimization, and therefore should not affect the behavior of compliant programs.  In a conforming implementation, the recursive call to `main()` is not in a tail position, so tail call optimization cannot be performed unless additional optimizations are performed first which place the call in a tail position.

Comment: I found the other part of the standard I was looking for, "If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, **and the value of the function call is used by the caller,** the behavior is undefined."  Emphasis mine.  So if your `int func()` does not have a `return;`, it is safe to call as long as you don't use the result.